# how to handle the parameterized query expects the parameter which was not supplied

Tags: c#, exception

I am inserting data on a button click.I am trying to handle exceptions for the field.My code is:

```
try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO omotnica (id,name,date,number)" +
                                    "VALUES(@id,@naziv_predmeta,@date,@number)";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idInt;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 300).Value = this.textBoxName.Text;
            try
            {
                DateTime datt = DateTime.Parse(textBoxDatumUpisa.Text);
                textBoxDatumUpisa.Text = datt.ToString("d/M/yyyy");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datt;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Date must be dd/MM/yyyy"); 
            }
            try
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@number", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxNumber.Text);

            }
            catch (SqlException e) when (e.Number == 8178)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("U must enter something");
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("It must be an integer");
            }

            con.Close();
             MessageBox.Show("Saved!");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" error" + ex.Message + ex.Source );

        }try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO omotnica (id,name,date,number)" +
                                    "VALUES(@id,@naziv_predmeta,@date,@number)";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idInt;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 300).Value = this.textBoxName.Text;
            try
            {
                DateTime datt = DateTime.Parse(textBoxDatumUpisa.Text);
                textBoxDatumUpisa.Text = datt.ToString("d/M/yyyy");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datt;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Date must be dd/MM/yyyy"); 
            }
            try
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@number", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxNumber.Text);

            }
            catch (SqlException e) when (e.Number == 8178)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("U must enter something");
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("It must be an integer");
            }

            con.Close();
             MessageBox.Show("Saved!");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" error" + ex.Message + ex.Source );

        }
```

When  I enter some string in the textBoxNumber,it fires up a FormatException and also an exception he parameterized query expects the parameter which was not supplied.When I leave the textBox blank it fires the parameterized query expects the parameter which was not supplied.
How to change that?Didn't I cover that exception with the SQLException catch?
I need it to fire a message box when it's blank or it's not integers inside the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert.ToInt32(String.Empty) will raise a FormatException because it cannot parse an empty string to a Int32 Value.

Converting an invalid string to Int32 will raise a FormatException but also a SQLException because the conversion fails and also the parameterized query, because it expects Int32.

You can catch System.Exception and switch on possible errors, instead of trying to catch two exceptions:

```
catch (Exception ex)            
{                
    if (ex is FormatException)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textboxName.Text){ 
            MessageBox.Show("U must enter something");
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("It must be an integer");
        }
        return; 
     } 
     else if (ex is SqlException) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return;
     }
   throw;
}
```

Comment: What about doing the validation before there's an exception?

Comment: That's a solution too. I was just clarifying why his code is not working as expected and one other approach to handle multiple exceptions...But I would also validate the textbox first leaving exceptions to handle more complicated things, like SQLException

Answer (score 1):

Just add: 
`if(textbox.Text == string.Empty) return;` at the start of the Click event so this doesn't happen. 
Instead of catching so many exeptions and showing a messageBox add `if`conditions and only handle exepctions that are supposed to happen.

And if you want  to recive a `int` input use a `numbericUpDown`

Answer (score 0):

You can safely try to convert without getting an exception like this

```
int num;
if (!Int32.TryParse(textBoxNumber.Text, out num)) {
    MessageBox.Show("It must be an integer");
    return;
}
```

And for text columns that may be empty

```
object textValue = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxName.Text)
    ? (object)textBoxName.Text
    : (object)DBNull.Value;
```

Note that you have to pass `DBNull.Value` and not just `null` as parameter, otherwise the parameter will be treated as missing.

If you want to show an error message instead:

```
if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxName.Text)) {
    MessageBox.Show("It must be an integer");
    return;
}
```

---

But the code gets very messy, if you try to convert textbox values, show error messages and construct an SQL statement at the same time.

Rather create a class for the values

```
class Omotnica 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

and in a frist step get the values into this class. This can also be done with [object data binding](http://www.tinesoft.com/csharp/link-a-windows-forms-control-to-an-object-data-binding). this does all the conversions for you!

Then setting up the SQL command will be much easier.

If you still want to handle the textbox values manually, you could create a method for this

```
private Omotnica GetValues()
{
    var o = new Omotnica();
    if (!Int32.TryParse(textBoxNumber.Text, out o.Number)) {
        return null;
    }

    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxName.Text)) {
        return null;
    }
    o.Name = textBoxName.Text;

    ... and so on
}
```

then you can clean up the SQL part like this

```
Omotnica o = GetValues();
if (o == null) {
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter something for number, name, ...");
} else {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO omotnica (id,name,date,number) VALUES (@id,...";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = o.ID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 300).Value = o.Name;
    ...
}
```

Looks much tidier, doesn't it?

Comment: I dont wanna pass a dbnull.value.I want it to show a message box,and let it for user to correct the field,and then insert it